# Definition of Spectrum in Logic

Tags: model-theory

So I want to practice with understanding the definition of Spectra. Basically, I understand it is the set consisting of all natural numbers n such that there is a model of phi with exactly n elements.

1) If we let L = {E} and let phi be a sentence which says that E is an equivalence relation in which every class has precisely three elements, how can we show that the spectrum of phi  is the set of naturals which are divisible by 3?

Writing it out, I'm thinking to let E = {E| a,b,c are Naturals} and I dont see how the divisible by 3 fits in

Comment: I can't make any sense out of "let E = {E| a,b,c are Naturals}". Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: there are three variables; ignore this if it doesnt make sense.

Comment: Some time ago I read a short note written by Burris about this spectrum (and available at https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/WWW/PDF/spectra.pdf ). This remark is only to tell you that I found these three pages very helpful to understand the notion, and perhaps you can take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ll do the first one completely to put you on the right track and let you think a bit more about the second.

Let $\varphi$ be the following sentence:

$$\begin{align*}
\forall x\,E(x,x)&\land\forall x,y\big(E(x,y)\to E(y,x)\big)\\
&\land\forall x,y,z\big(E(x,y)\land E(y,z)\to E(x,z)\big)\;;
\end{align*}$$

it says that $E$ is an equivalence relation. The first conjunct says that $E$ is reflexive; the second, that $E$ is symmetric; and the third, that $E$ is transitive. Now let $\psi$ be the following sentence:

$$\forall x\exists y,z\Big(E(x,y)\land E(x,z)\land x\ne y\land x\ne z\land y\ne z\land\forall w\big(E(x,w)\to(w=x\lor w=y\lor w=z\big)\Big)\;,$$

it says that each element is related by $E$ to exactly two other elements. (Make sure that you see why this is so.) Thus, $\varphi\land\psi$ is a sentence saying that $E$ is an equivalence relation such every equivalence class of $E$ has exactly three elements. If $\mathfrak A$ is a finite model of $\varphi\land\psi$ with $k$ equivalence classes, then $|\mathfrak A|=3k$. Clearly we can define such a model for each $k\in\Bbb N$, so the spectrum of $\varphi\land\psi$ is $\{3k:k\in\Bbb N\}$, the set of non-negative multiples of $3$.

Comment: @mary: I’m confused: the first question pretty much requires that you know what an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) is.

Comment: @mary: This should at least get you started. Try a model that has a one-place relation $A$ and a binary function $f$ and a sentence that says that $f$ is one-to-one with domain $A\times A$ and that everything is in the range of $f$.

Comment: so I have to write that in formal notation. It looks good :)