# Spectrum of elements in a set

Tags: logic, model-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a spectrum. Is $\mathbb{N}\setminus X$ a spectrum?

By spectrum, we mean that it is the set containing all natural numbers $n$ s.t. there is a model of $\phi$ with exactly $n$ elements (for some first-order sentence $\phi$ in some language $\mathcal{L}$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Edited in response to comments)

I don't know the answer - nobody does! This is an open problem, which means that proving that spectra are closed under complements or providing a counterexample (an example of a spectrum $X$ whose complement $\mathbb{N}\setminus X$ is not a spectrum) would be a new mathematical result.

In a comment on your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330084/definition-of-spectrum-in-logic), boumol posted a link to the following note on finite spectra by Stanley Burris: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/WWW/PDF/spectra.pdf

The following paragraph from these notes answers your question:

"In 1956, Asser looked at the question of whether the complement of
a spectrum is again a spectrum - the problem is still open. A fascinating
result was proved by Jones and Selman in 1974 when they showed that a
subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is a spectrum iff it can be accepted by some nondeterministic Turing machine in time $2^{O(n)}$. From this it follows that if NP is closed under complements, i.e., NP = co-NP, then spectra are also closed under complements. Consequently to show that spectra are not closed under complements is at least as difficult as showing NP $\neq$ co-NP, and hence P $\neq$ NP."

Explaining the classes NP and co-NP is outside the scope of this response, but the take-away message from this paragraph is that if you could show that spectra are not closed under complements, you would also have managed to solve one of the most important open problems in mathematics and computer science by proving that P$\neq$NP. So this is *hard*.

Comment: I'm looking for a sentence, not really a discussion which translates our definition of spectrum. Could you please include it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment at all. The question you ask is open, and the discussion I quoted elaborates on why the problem is open. Do you know what "open problem" means?

Comment: Open as in flexible response? I dont understand the NP and co-NP can you formulate in this question?

Comment: @Pål GD: Please don't make significant edits to other people's answers, unless those answers are intentionally set up for community editing. You are always welcome to write your own answer, and I think you could write a useful one here. The practice on math.SE is not quite the same as other stackexchange sites - we strongly discourage edits to other authors' answers apart from very minor ones such as formatting fixes. That practice (of not editing others' answers) is also part of the culture of MathOverflow, which predated this site.

Comment: @CarlMummert This was a suggested edit which was independently approved by two editors.  The edit was simply adding a link to an answer about the P vs NP question of mary, and adding a definition (with reference) of Asser's problem.